# Android - Is there any reason why my app should crash when I add a sound file to raw?

Tags: android, audio, crash

My app crashes when I try to open in. The only change I've made was adding a .ogg file to my res/raw directory. It's really weird. I haven't added any codes or made any other changes. I just dragged a sound file into raw and compiled. It just keeps saying "unfortunately blah has stopped". Are there any obvious things I should check?

MainActivity.onCreate:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.engine_layout);
        myEngineView = (EngineView) findViewById(R.id.engineviewid);
        myEngineView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    }
```

I get this in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thing/com.example.thing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at com.example.thing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
E/AndroidRuntime(12560):    ... 11 more
E/AppErrorDialog(  338): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
E/Trace   (12585): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12585): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thing/com.example.thing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at com.example.thing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
E/AndroidRuntime(12585):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Make sure your file name includes lowercase letters, numbers or underscore only.

Comment: The title is source.ogg

Comment: I have also added same file "source.ogg" is raw folder, but I have not found any error

Comment: Could you add error log for more details.

Comment: Thank you adding code. Could you add **code of MainActivity.onCreate method....** this method throws error here.